# In Magento how to setup sale tax for all states in U.S.?

Tags: php, excel, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

My E-Commerce store are planning to sale all over the United State. But when I look up the sale tax online, all states have different sale tax and each city have different sale tax also.

Example: Florida state

- State Rate = 6%
- City Rate of Boca Raton, Florida = 6%
- City Rate of Brandon, Florida = 6%

http://www.sale-tax.com/Florida

But in Magento Only allow you to set up Tax Rate for the one state but not separate cities.

Someone please teach me how to set up tax rate for each state/city correct.

Best Regards.

Comment: This is a US CPA tax accountant question. You really need to get one and find out what your State Tax liability is. Where is your US presence? Due to the way Interstate Commerce was addressed under Federal Law, you may only need to charge sales tax in the state where your business is registered and operates (mult-state locations, tax per state).

Comment: If I understand it correctly your saying, If I registered my e-commerce website in **New York City**, when ever customer purchase in New York Area I will charge them tax. If a customer is outside of NYC, and he/she ordered in Florida state I won't be charging them any tax?

Comment: Yes, that would be true, as this is a legal and taxation question, please consult a CPA in NYC to verify exactly what municipal taxes, county taxes and state taxes you have liability for. You will at a bare minimum in the example given, be liable for State and if applicable, County Sales Tax. A company I have experience with does e-commerce in the US. Based in Oregon, they have no state sales tax, but because they have a Florida storefront, they must collect Florida State and County Sales Tax. Drop Ship is the exception to this, your vendor will let you know.

Comment: hmm...so my suppliers should know questions like this right?

Comment: It would be a place to start.